# Any source to find distance between vertices in generalized Petersen graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am trying to find the distance between vertices of generalized Petersen graphs
$P(n,k)$. For $n = 50$ and $k<\frac{n}{2}$ I did everything manually. I manually wrote down a shortest path between any two vertices. However, it is really cumbersome to find the same for higher values of $n$. Is there any site/software/link to find a shortest distance between vertices of generalized Petersen graphs?
I will be really grateful for the help. Thanks for the help.

P.S. I tried Mathematica with the help of a friend and got to know that I can get radius and diameter using this. But I am interested in the shortest paths.
**The generalized Petersen graphs $P(n,1)$ and generalized Petersen graphs
$P(n,2)$ are shown below.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be only a limited number of cases to consider. E.g. if both are on the outer circuit, would the two distance jump to the middle be worth the speed up on the inner k circuit? For the inner circuit if k,n are not coprime then there will be cases when you have to jump to the outer. I think it can be proven that you'd never have need to jump back and forth more than once.

Comment: @PaulChilds Yeah, I considered one vertex from the outer circle and one from the inner vertices. Rest can be generalized

Comment: That should be the easiest case, with d mod k or k-d mod k giving the number of hops on the outer

Comment: You should specify if you are interested in the distance in terms of number of edges, or distance in terms of position in the plane for a given embedding.  If the two  answers are in the wrong direction, we need to know.  Your comment to Paul Childs seem to indicate that.

Comment: @monalisa: Assuming you're talking about edge-distance between vertices, have you tried calculating powers of the adjacency matrix, $A$? (Mathematica makes short work of these computations.) The $(i,j)$-th entry of $A^k$ tells how many paths of length $k$ join vertices $i$ and $j$. So, the first $k$ for which the $(i,j)$-th entry is non-zero is the distance between those vertices.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please note that we can readily compute several quantities from the diagram. Two most important quantities are the length of the arc, $s = r\theta$ and the length of the chord, $c = 2r \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$

Once we know these two quantities, the rest of the job is easy. For shortest path computation, we need to know the length of the edges of the graph. Here the lengths may be computed using simple formulas.

For example, consider the graph 
[P(4,1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Petersen_graph#/media/File:Generalized_Petersen_9_2_Hamiltonicity.svg)

Two inner/outer vertices are either connected by a chord or by an arc. An outer and an inner vertex are connected by a straight line. So in all the cases, the length of the edges are known. Now the rest should be easy if you use some standard algorithm like [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Many such algorithms are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)

Let me cite an example using P(4, 1) following your naming convention. 
[image: P(4, 1)]
Assume that the outer vertices are $u_0, u_1, u_2, u_3$ and the corresponding inner vertices are $v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3$

Now if you want to compute the shortest path between any two vertices $a$ and $b$, then there can be only three cases:

1. They both are of type $u$
2. They both are of type $v$
3. One of them is of type $u$ and the other one is of type $v$

The graph has $8$ vertices and $12$ edges. Note that we do not have any arcs as our edges. Let us assume that the radius of the inner circle is $r$ and the radius of the outer circle is $R$. Then there are only three types of edges: Distance between two vertices of type $u$ is $e_1 = \sqrt{2}R$, Distance between two vertices of type $v$ is $e_2 = \sqrt{2}r$ and the edges connecting $u$ and $v$ are of length $e_3 = (R-r)$

Here is the adjacency matrix:

\begin{array}{c|cccccccc} \text{vertices} & u_0 & u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & v_0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\ \hline u_0 & 0 & e_1 & 0 & e_1 & e_3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ u_1 & e_1 & 0 & e_1 & 0 & 0 & e_3 & 0 & 0\\ u_2 & 0 & e_1 & 0 & e_1 & 0 & 0 & e_3 & 0\\ u_3 & e_1 & 0 & e_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e_3\\ v_0 & e_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e_2 & 0 & e_2\\ v_1 & 0 & e_3 & 0 & 0 & e_2 & 0 & e_2 & 0\\ v_2 & 0 & 0 & e_3 & 0 & 0 & e_2 & 0 & e_2\\ v_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e_3 & e_2 & 0 & e_2 & 0 \end{array}

As an illustration, I set $R = \sqrt{2}$, $r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and computed all the pair-wise shortest paths using Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

\begin{array}{c|cccccccc} \text{distances} & u_0 & u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & v_0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\ \hline u_0 & 0 & 2 & 3.172 & 2 & 0.586 & 1.586 & 2.586& 1.586\\ u_1 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3.172 & 1.586 & 0.586 & 1.586 & 2.586\\ u_2 & 3.172 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2.586 & 1.586 & 0.586 & 1.586\\ u_3 & 2 & 3.586 & 2 & 0 & 1.586 & 2.586 & 1.586 & 0.586\\ v_0 & 0.586 & 2 & 2.586 & 1.586 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1\\ v_1 & 1.586 & 1 & 1.586 & 2.586 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ v_2 & 2.586 & 2 & 0.586 & 1.586 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ v_3 & 1.586 & 3 & 1.586 & 0.586 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \end{array}

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that the vertices lie on a circle, so you can compute the coordinates easily. If the vertices on the inner polygon are on a circle of radius $r$, they are at $(r \cos \frac {2m\pi}n, r\sin \frac {2m\pi}n)$ for $m=0,1,2,\ldots n-1$.  The outer polygon has radius $R$, so make the substitution.  Now computing the distance is easy.  The distances between the two sets of vertices are just $R-r$.  The distance for the chords of the inner polygon are $r\sqrt {(1-\cos \frac {2k\pi}n)^2+\sin^2 \frac {2k\pi}n}$.  The distance for the chords on the outer polygon is $R\sqrt {(1-\cos \frac {2\pi}n)^2+\sin^2 \frac {2\pi}n}$

For your $P(n,2)$ example I was considering the inner edges, like from $u_1$ to $u_3,$ to be straight.  The edge between a $u$ and a $v$ has length $R-r$.  The edge between two $v$s has length $R\sqrt {(1-\cos \frac {2\pi}n)^2+\sin^2 \frac {2\pi}n}$ and the edge between two $u$s has length $r\sqrt {(1-\cos \frac {4\pi}n)^2+\sin^2 \frac {4\pi}n}$.  The $v$s are neighboring points on a circle divided into $n$ equal segments.  The $u$s are separated by $1$, which accounts for the extra factor $2$ in the angles.

Comment: I think you'll find the generalised Petersen graphs are defined as having unit *geodetic* distance for every edge.

Comment: @PaulChilds:  I just used the usual embedding in the plane with all the vertices on two circles.  I think that was what OP was asking.

Comment: @Ross This formula requires the radius of the generalized Petersen graph. And for that, we have to find eccentricity of vertices which automatically requires us to find the distance between vertices. I am quite confused here

Comment: @monalisa:  the pictures I saw in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Petersen_graph) had the vertices on two concentric circles.  If you are talking about something else, please describe it.

Comment: @RossMillikan Could you please go through the following link?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedPetersenGraph.html

Comment: That agrees with the Wikipedia article I noted.  All the vertices are on two concentric circles, equally spaced and lined up.  You can choose the two radii as you wish.  My answer applies.  There are three types of edges and I give the length for each.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sir, could you please explain with an example? Please.

Comment: For an outer polygon, I understood that the length of the polygon is $n$, like a cycle of length $n$. But what about the inner polygon where you took radius as $r$?

Comment: If you put the $x$ axis through $u_1, and $v_1$, we have $u_1=(r,0), u_3=(r\cos \frac {4\pi}n,r\sin \frac {4\pi n}$.  I then computed the distance $u_1u_3$ to get the square root.  It is a chord with twice the central angle.

Comment: @RossMillikan Based on the wording of the question and the subsequent comments on your answer, I have a strong gut feeling that the original poster was referring to the *graph* distances between pairs of vertices (i.e. the number of edges in the shortest path connecting them), rather than the lengths of lines in one specific embedding of this graph in a plane. The misunderstanding was only fueled further by words like "radius" have both geometrical and graph-theoretical meaning :-)